# ECSlidingViewController, start with firsttopview slided to the right

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I'm using https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController. And it works very good. Now I would like to start with the FirstTopView slided slightly to the right when I start the app.

[Here is a picture how I want it to start.](http://oi49.tinypic.com/2hd2tlk.jpg)

If I use, in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad (FirstTopViewController):

```
[self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:nil];
```

It will animate the FirstTopView to the right, but I want it to be there straight away.

Thx in advanced.

Comment: Added a picture to describe the problem better. I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in viewWillAppear